# public static member function cannot be defined in cpp file

Tags: c++

I have a class with a public static member function. It seems that I can't define that function in a cpp file (with a very vague error) but I can compile fine when I define the function in a header. How can this be?

cmdlineparser.h

```
#ifndef __CMD_LINE_PARSER_H__
#define __CMD_LINE_PARSER_H__

//#include <getopt.h>
//#include "cmdlineargs.h"

class CmdLineParser
{
private:
    //CmdLineParser() {}
    //static void printCmdLineHelp();
public:
    //static CmdLineArgs parse(int argc, char** argv);
    static int parse();

};

#endif
```

cmdlineparser.cpp

```
#include "cmdlineparser.h"

int CmdLineParser::parse()
{
     return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "cmdlineparser.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Parse the command line arguments.
    //int cmdLineArgs = CmdLineParser::parse(argc, argv);
    int cmdLineArgs = CmdLineParser::parse();
    return 0;
}
```

Error: undefined reference to `CmdLineParser::parse()`

It compiles when I put the definition in the header:

```
static int parse(){return 0;}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain you are compiling and linking cmdlineparser.cpp?

Comment: `__CMD_LINE_PARSER_H__` is a reserved identifier. You should come up with another header guard.

Comment: Maybe better use #pragma once as include guard, if your compiler supports it.

Comment: You were right, Francois I wasn't pulling in the cmdlineparser with the make file. Thanks.